# no sounds in slackware 14.01?

Tags: linux, audio, kde, slackware

I have laptop hp pavilion 15n245se
I recently installed Slackware 14.01 but there is no sounds but running phonon and testing produces sounds (piece of music) and when I press the raise volume key in the keyboard it shows that volume is 0% and it never raise up
I am new to Slackware and I don't know what extra information should I give but please if you need any ask in a comment !
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and then open alsamixer and check that your volume controls are not muted. Use the arrow keys to move across all the selections. It's possible that the Master or the PCM control are just muted. You also can use the arrow keys up and down to increase or decrease volume.